# Redirect url after contact form submission and include function

Tags: url, redirect

I have created the below code for my website www.pearsonkoutcherlaw.com:

```
<?php
                if (isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) {
        header("location: http://www.pearsonkoutcherlaw.com/abl-form-submit/"); exit;
                    print "<p style=\"font-weight:bold;\">Form has been sent!</p>";
                    print '<p>Thank you for your submission. </p>';
                    print "<p>What You Sent</p>";

                    print "<b>Name:</b><br/>".$name."<br/><br/>";
                    print "<b>Email:</b><br/>".$email."<br/><br/>";
                    print "<b>Phone:</b><br/>".$phone."<br/><br/>";
                    print "<b>Message:</b><br/>".$message."<br/><br/>";

                } else {      ?>``
```

So, after submission, the user is redirected to http://www.pearsonkoutcherlaw.com/abl-form-submit/.  However, I also want the print functions, "Form has been sent", "Thank you for your submission." to appear on the redirect page?

How do I do that?

Thanks,

Megan

Comment: Why do you use the header() function? You could add an action to the form itself pointing to the target page.

Then use your php code on that page.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I apologize, but I am very new at this.  Could you please explain how I would do that?

Comment: You should have a form somewhere which is being submitted. Search for the form-tag and edit the action attribute.

<form action="abl-form-submit" method="post">

Once you submit this form, it redirects you to /abl-form-submit